# Tiny number of high rep users and the consequences

Tags: discussion

A user from outside our community mentioned something that I found rather interesting and I'm not sure it's been discussed here before. Our website only has 17 users with a total rep >= 10k. I did not check the following myself, but as I've heard, it's the lowest number of all graduated websites, and even lower than that of some beta sites.

Is this a valid problem that needs attention and immediate fixing? Are there any consequences that could be caused by it (e.g. if a graduated site started not meeting the criteria for a beta to graduate anymore, though the rep amount specified on area51 is 3k, so this might not be the case here)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could at least do a cursory investigation before passing rumor. There are a number of graduated sites that have fewer users below 10k:

- [Android Enthusiasts: 16](https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)
- [Bicycles: 7](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)
- [Christianity: 12](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)
- [Graphic Design: 7](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)
- [Personal Finance and Money: 10](https://money.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)
- And so on...

How many have *active* users above 10k? Hard to say.

No, this is not something that needs immediate fixing.

Maybe everyone can starting voting more often. Not only vote up posts that are great, but posts that are good too.

Comment: My bad, 17 users seemed like such a low number it felt surprising for it to not be true. 7 users is baffling imo. But since it doesn't require immediate fixing, I guess it's not that big of an issue.

Comment: Really, the 3k rep level is more important. Voting to close questions is something we need more of.

Comment: Statistics on 3k and 10k rep users across SE here - http://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/query/223453/user-count-by-reputation-across-stack-exchange

Comment: This has now been edited to show all privilege levels. Not that each includes ALL users who have that privilege: e.g. the 17 10k+ users are included in the "create posts" (1 rep) level.  Thank goodness its cached because this horrible query I wrote (I'm bad at SQL) took almost a minute to run.